# Problems with decimals and scientific notation in Python 2.6.6

Tags: python, string, decimal, scientific-notation

I'm having difficulty with decimal values that I need to use for arithmetic in some cases and as strings in others. Specifically I have a list of rates, ex:

```
rates=[0.1,0.000001,0.0000001]
```

And I am using these to specify the compression rates for images. I need to initially have these values as numbers because I need to be able to sort them to make sure they are in a specific order. I also want to be able to convert each of these values to strings so I can 1) embed the rate into the filename and 2) log the rates and other details in a CSV file. The first problem is that any float with more than 6 decimal places is in scientific format when converted to a string:

```
>>> str(0.0000001)
'1e-07'
```

So I tried using Python's Decimal module but it is also converting some floats to scientific notation (seemingly contrary to the docs I've read). Ex:

```
>>> Decimal('1.0000001')
Decimal('1.0000001')
# So far so good, it doesn't convert to scientific notation with 7 decimal places
>>> Decimal('0.0000001')
Decimal('1E-7')
# Scientific notation, back where I started.
```

I've also looking into string formatting as suggested in multiple posts, but I've not had any luck. Any suggestions and pointers are appreciated by this Python neophyte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the string format then:

```
["%.8f" % (x) for x in rates]
```

This yields `['0.10000000', '0.00000100', '0.00000010']`. Works with `Decimal`, too.

Answer (score 5):

```
'{0:f}'.format(Decimal('0.0000001'))
```

The above should work for you

Comment: would you know how to do the same thing in Python 2.6.6?

Answer (score 4):

See [`% formatting`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), especially the floating point conversions:

> 'e'   Floating point exponential format (lowercase).  (3)
>
> 'E'   Floating point exponential format (uppercase).  (3)
>
> 'f'   Floating point decimal format.  (3)
>
> 'F'   Floating point decimal format.  (3)
>
> 'g'   Floating point format. Uses lowercase exponential format if exponent is less than -4 or not less than precision, decimal format otherwise.  (4)
>
> 'G'   Floating point format. Uses uppercase exponential format if exponent is less than -4 or not less than precision, decimal format otherwise.  (4)

An example, using `f` format.

```
>>> ["%10.7f" %i for i in rates]
[' 0.1000000', ' 0.0000010', ' 0.0000001']
>>>
```

You can also use the newer (starting 2.6) [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```
>>> ['{0:10.7f}'.format(i) for i in rates]
[' 0.1000000', ' 0.0000010', ' 0.0000001']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using f-strings:

```py
>>> rates = [0.1, 0.000001, 0.0000008]
>>> [f'{r:.7f}' for r in rates]
['0.1000000', '0.0000010', '0.0000008']
```

The string format `{r:.7f}` indicates the number of digits used after the decimal point, which in this case is 7.