# Sorting decimals in python

Tags: python, sorting, decimal

I have a list

```
    list1 = ["1.10","1.1","1.23","2.20","2.2"]
```

and I used

```
    list1.sort(key=float)
```

which gave output

```
   list1 = ["1.10","1.1","1.23","2.20","2.2"]
```

However I am looking for this:

```
   list1 = ["1.1","1.10","1.23","2.2","2.20"]
```

Any ideas how I can go about doing this?

Comment: *And I used list1.sort(key=int) which gave output* Did you really? What implementation and version of Python are you using? The only "output" I get from trying that is a `ValueError`.

Comment: First: You need `key=float`. Second: Python uses stable sorting. So `1.10` being equal to `1.1` will always occur in this order because of the original order. A simple `list1.sort()` will produce this behavior for this single list, because it will compare strings, not numbers

Comment: You do realize that 1.10 == 1.1 and 2.20 == 2.2, that those pairs of numbers are *exactly* the same and there's no reason why you should expect they sort one way or another...

Comment: You may want `key=decimal.Decimal` rather than `key=float`. It won't make a difference for these examples, but for your real data it may.

Comment: Voting to close since the code presented couldn't have possibly produced the result presented.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with decimals and scientific notation in Python 2.6.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785996/problems-with-decimals-and-scientific-notation-in-python-2-6-6)

Comment: @Shashank Sorry made a mistake. It should be float not int

Comment: @JBernardo thank you very much, that worked. Could you submit it as an answer?

Comment: @GregHewgill yes I do, but that is not the point here, is it.

Comment: @VaibhavMule no that is different from my question

Comment: @Robᵩ why are you voting to close it just because I made an error in the question? What's up the all the down votes anyways?

Comment: @JBernardo opps, jumped the gun there. this only sorts within the numbers but not among them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take the length of the string into account you have to tell it to the key function. We have to construct a key where the `float` value is considered first and the length of the string second.

The easiest way to do this is to create a tuple with those two values.

```
>>> list1 = ["1.10","1.1","1.23","2.20","2.2"]
>>> list1.sort(key=lambda x: (float(x), len(x)))
>>> list1
['1.1', '1.10', '1.23', '2.2', '2.20']
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution, but it's as much as I could do to get it started:

```
string1 = ["1.10","1.1","1.23","2.2","2.20"]
for x in string1:
    if x.find('0') > 0:
        place = string1.index(x)
        string1.remove(x)
        string1.insert(place+1, x)
print (string1)
```

The only problem it's having now is as the list iterates, it keeps going over the same values again and again, pushing them forward. Perhaps a function could prevent that from happening.